# VS2012 project file into makefile

Tags: linux, visual-studio, makefile, cross-platform, vcproj

hello all i'm developing cross-platform system.
I know that we have make it so. and some others like sln2mak.
however they do not support Visual Studio 2012.

does anyone know if something like this exists for VS2012 project files?

Comment: I wrote my Makefile by hand when I faced that situation - the thing will be more readable and logical as a result.  Nonetheless, if I wanted to develop cross-platform, I would use MSBuild for the microsoft compilers and GNU make for GCC.   (And where possible, I would use GCC on Windows).

Comment: i have to convert 39 little project into makefiles. i rather not do it by hand. :D also after that using it in a build server.

Comment: It's still not obvious that doing it by hand isn't the easiest thing -- especially if they are all similar.  And do you really need 39 different Makefiles, or can you make one to rule them all? Still I would maintain separate build systems for the two platform types.

Comment: BTW: a Makefile that works with nmake is not going to work on Unix.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala doing it by hand is a solution i'm aware of. however this is not my question. i want to learn about other possibilities as well. thank you

Comment: Good point.  And while I am not actually answering your question, wonder are you planning to use nmake or GNU make under Windows?

Comment: I would use one build system. Cygwin's make is probably the best on Windows (`-jn` works well for instance, the build environment is very close to unix, and it all well works inside VisualStudio). You will have to take care to parameterise the compiler in your makefile(s) in some way (`gcc` or `cl.exe`?).